# Publication on the contamination of used needels by addicts

Tags: infection, injury, public-health, needles

I am looking for **scientific publications** on the likelyhood to get infected with a specific disease by used needles which were thrown away by careless addicts.

Which viruses can be found statistically on needles in specific regions?

I am looking for a statement like

> N percent of the collected needles in area X were contaminated with Y.

Comment: I suspect that infections caused by needles tossed by careless addicts are vanishingly rare. So if someone is asking which diseases are prevalent among addicts in a given area, epidemiological data would give much better answers. Or does your question go more toward how much risk such needles present?

Comment: Yes, finally my question is about the risk. I have split the question in two parts. a) which diseases are typical? b) what is the probability to get infected?

Comment: Most needle transfers of diseases refer to sharing of needles, not carelessly discarded ones. HIV in particular really does not survive long outside the body. I'm a bit doubtful anyone has gone around collecting discarded needles to test them but I could be wrong.

Comment: I also doubt you can get an useful answer about what percent of needles are contaminated. Would you accept an answer with some case reports or such?